# Expectation Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Can someone help show me a simple way to show:

$$\mathbb{E}(S_t)= S_0e^{\mu  t}$$

for

$$ S_t = S_0\exp\left( \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right)t + \sigma W_t\right) $$

from this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral to solve is:
$E$$[S_s]$=$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$S_s$$exp((\mu-\frac{1}2\sigma^2)s+\sigma W_s)$$exp$$(W_s^2/2t)$$dW$$/(\sqrt(2\pi t))$
From this integral the expression $S_s$$exp((\mu-\frac{1}2\sigma^2)s$ can be factored out.
The remaining expression inside the integral is $exp(\sigma W_s)$$exp$$(W_s^2/2t)$=$exp(\sigma W_s+$$W_s^2/2t)$
This expression can be simplified by "completing the square". This will then provide an expression that allows to cancel out $exp(\frac{1}2\sigma^2)s$.
The remaining integral equals one so that only the expression outside the integral remains, which is $E$$[S_s]$=$S_s$$exp(\mu s$).
Probably there are some mistakes in the expressions above but hopefully the idea becomes clear.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: For a normal random variable $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma),$ show that

$$\mathbb{E}[e^X]=e^{\mu+\frac 12 \sigma^2}$$

Comment: I have tried doing this but am having some troubles with the integral! also I found a helpful pdf but am having some troubles understanding step (10) and (11):http://www.soarcorp.com/research/geometric_brownian_motion.pdf